# GIS operations to create a union from a polyline plus a polygon

Tags: geometry, turf

I've got access to JS geospatial library (turf.js), which has a full suite of GIS operations available. But, I'm stuck on the terms for what I'm trying to do.

In laymans terms, I wish to extend the red polygon below to also include the area described by the blue polyline. But, I can't use a union operation since it will only work on two polygons.

Is there another term for what I'm trying to do?

[image: subject shapes]

The desired end result would be as if we were generating the union of these two polygons:
[image: two polygons]

Comment: Please edit your question add picture of desired final polygon. Also more info about blue line: is it single line string or it consists of two line strings? Also add info about points where blue lines cross orange ones. Can those points be anywhere or is there some rule?

Comment: Also, some GeoJSON data representing the situation described would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks + TomazicM - have added new diagram to further explain what the expected result would look like.  
I haven't added GeoJSON data.  It's not a specific answer I'm looking for, just an introduction to the names of the operation(s) I would be performing.

Comment: Your so called resultant polygon is not union of polygons but two separate polygons overlapping. Also the blue "polygon" seems not to be a polygon, since there are some crossed lines at the top. Also there is no explanation in your question about the role of the bright blue point.